# ASP NET MVC 5 SessionState

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an Intranet web app and i am using the same List to generate 2 views, the list is updated every 60 seconds.

My question is "Is there a better way (security wise) to persist this list?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally SessionState in MVC is asking for trouble, MVC strives to be stateless (just like the websites in general). Odds are it will cause you pain at one point or another due to the fact that it can make requests non-deterministic.

How is the list updated? Is it a a file? A database? Either way I feel like a repository pattern would make more sense. On first request cache it and save the time you last updated, then on each subsequent Get if DateTime.Now > TimeLastGotten + 1 minute get it again and override the cache. This has the added bonus of being much easier to test and mock than using Session.

Comment: So its better if I use something like this? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That would totally work. You can go with something as simple as a static IEnumerable field, or something more robust like the .net cache implementation (what you linked), you could build a super in depth cache your self if you wanted. Pick whatever fits your needs. My usual pattern is to make an IFooRepository and then I can make many implementations of the repository with different caching or no caching and just register which ever one I want with my dependency resolver. This allows you to easily remove caching if you ever need to.

Make sense?

Comment: Awesome! so something like this is "the correct way"?

Cache cache = new Cache();
cache["saveList"] = ListToSave;

and the same thing in ViewResult I want to use the list on?

List list = cache["saveList"];

Comment: I managed to get it working, thank you for your time and help !:)